# iTerm resize screen problem

Tags: terminal, iterm

I'm encountering an issue where the iTerm screen becomes misconfigured when my MacBook Air M2 changes the monitor or goes into sleep mode. To resolve this, I have to close the session and restart it. This is quite inconvenient.

Has anyone else experienced this problem, especially with a MacBook Air M2? If so, what steps can I take to prevent or fix this issue?

I appreciate any advice or insights you can provide. Thank you in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a straight answer to solve your issue but I can provide some elements to help (my reputation isn"t high enough to just comment your question).

I have the same problem of black section appearing on iTerm2 since I use it. It appeared both on my MacBook Pro M1 Pro and my MacBook Pro M2 Pro. The only relevant [post I found was this one](https://gitlab.com/gnachman/iterm2/-/issues/9359), but it states that the issue it resolved.

Though, I since found a workaround to not close and lose your session : switch to mission control to view your workspaces, and slide you iTerm workspace from one screen to another and do it again to put it back on the screen it was, it should at least get rid of the black band (until the next time it occurs). An other technique, that I found less convenient, is to quit fullscreen and put it back (it can be done with the shortcut  + <kbd>F</kbd>)

Comment: I am going to test